# Continuous functions agreeing almost everywhere

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory

Let $\Omega$ be a (non-empty) subset of $\mathbf{R}^n$. If $f$ and $g$ are continuous real-valued functions agreeing almost everywhere on $\Omega$, do they agree on the whole of $\Omega$? I am not particularly interested in Lebesgue measure, as the answer seems to be yes (it seems that if $\Sigma$ is a subset of $\Omega$ such that $\Omega-\Sigma$ has Lebesgue measure $0$, then $\Sigma$ is dense in $\Omega$, if I am not mistaken.) But you may assume certain regularity properties of the underlying measure, maybe that it be a Radon measure or whatever.

Comment: If the measure is counting measure supported on a discrete subset, the answer is clearly no. But you are right that the answer is positive for the Lebesgue measure, for trivial reasons: If two continuous function differ in a point, they differ in a neighbourhood, and a nonempty open set has nonzero measure.

Comment: I fail to get the question.

Comment: As a continuation to my previous comment, if $\Omega$ is not open, even Lebesgue measure is not enough: For example let $\Omega$ be a hyperplane. Then its Lebesgue measure is zero, so *any* two functions are equal a.e. on $\Omega$.

Comment: very helpful Harald! thx

Answer (score 4):

This is not true in general: just take the measure to be a point mass (assuming that $\Omega$ has at least 2 points!).

If say $\Omega=\mathbb R^n$, this will hold (for any continuous $f,g$) if and only if the measure of every nonempty open set is $>0$ (which means exactly that the complement of any set with measure $0$ is dense in $\mathbb R^n$). Indeed, one direction is clear (as you already observed). For the converse, assume that $\mu(O)=0$ for some open set $O\neq \emptyset$. One can certainly find two continuous functions $f\neq g$ on $\mathbb R^n$ with supports contained in $O$. Then $f=0=g$ almost everywhere wrt $\mu$.